# search in vim records separated by mulit-char sequence

Tags: vim, search

I have been looking online for an answer for weeks now, but I am still at a loss...

I have a file ( being edited in VIM ) containing multi-line records - essentially  paragraphs separated by "\n\n X ", where X may be different characters.

I need, inside vim, to find all records which contain all sought words (and highlight sought words), possibly when those words are search patterns themselves.

This could be put also this way: How do I tell vim to find results of a multi-line search pattern, where such results are not to contain sequence "\n\n [a-Z.,+*$#@!] " (because such sequence separates the sought records and ever appears inside them).

Thanks!

edit#1: To better explain, I am adding 5 samples of records, between each record is : \n\n\s_\s\d+ (where \s is 0x20 and _ is one of several possible ascii chars) :

```
 * 110000000018BBRT Phasellus aliquet blandit tellus,
sed sollicitudin augue accumsan vel.

 + 978000220019KML  Mauris et hendrerit dolor, a dapibus ante.
  * Vestibulum viverra ultricies urna.

 ! 020007005289KML  Vestibulum a malesuada enim.
Cras a efficitur est.
Suspendisse in nulla a justo finibus tincidunt.

 x 949317999999BTVN Sed facilisis massa eget mattis feugiat.
  o Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

 v 949317999999BTV  Vestibulum at lectus at neque malesuada venenatis.
 Aliquam.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this helps you, but here's a pattern that matches any combination of `red` and `blue` (in either order) only if both appear in a block delimited by two empty lines (`\n\n\n`; the first newline is from the end of the last block, then two for the new lines; you need to adapt this to your exact separator).

This builds on the basic pattern to match both `red` and `blue` within a line in either order:

```
/\%(red.*blue\)\|\%(blue.*red\)/
```

And then extends each branch's simple `.*` to (multi-line) blocks that don't have `\n\n\n` in between them.

One branch for `red...blue` blocks, and another for `blue...red` blocks:

```
/\%(red\_.\{-}\%(\n\n\n\|blue\)\)\@>\%(blue\)\@<=/
/\%(blue\_.\{-}\%(\n\n\n\|red\)\)\@>\%(red\)\@<=/
```

The end result just combines both, and switches to the old regexp engine [due to a bug in Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3651).

```
/\%#=1\%(\%(red\_.\{-}\%(\n\n\n\|blue\)\)\@>\%(blue\)\@<=\)\|\%(blue\_.\{-}\%(\n\n\n\|red\)\)\@>\%(red\)\@<=/
```

If that sounds incomprehensible or way too complex, maybe another approach is needed (like first joining all blocks together into single lines, making this a much easier match). As you give very little context and no example content, I cannot comment further on this.

Comment: wow! this seems to work!!!  thank you! I've just added a sample of 5 records to the original post with the right delimiter of \n\n\s.\s\d+ ... I've tried to replace your "\n\n\n" with "\n\n . ", and so far it works on everything I tried, thank you!!!  
  Now I'll try to figure out how to generate the right pattern from the last one to four words that were searched. Ideally I press <leader>3 and the last 3 words ( or SIMPLE /lo.em ips.m/ searched patterns) will be automagically used to create this crazy but functional search pattern! If I don't manage, I'll have to ask here ... again ...

Comment: Hrm, is there a way to extend this such that we search for red AND blue AND !green? I.e. for records that do contain "red" and "blue" but do not contain "green"? I just tried `/\%#=1\%(\%(red\_.\{-}\%(\n\n\n\|green\|blue\)\)\@>\%(blue\)\@<=\)\|\%(blue\_.\{-}\%(\n\n\n\|green\|red\)\)\@>\%(red\)\@<=/` but that doesn't seem to do the trick ... :(

Comment: Asserting that something does _not_ match is difficult in regular expressions, and this one already is very complex. I would try to make `green` an alternative block separator, so use `\n\n\n\|green` instead of `\n\n\n`.